Prime NG carousel horizontal aligment of items
I have a Prime NG carousel with logo's (PNGs) as elements. These logos have not the same height. Is it possible to center these logo's horizontally. The behaviour of Prime NG carousel is that items are horizontally at the top, but I want to center them in the middle.
I tried to apply the following css to p-carousel and the img respectively:
container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
   padding-left: 10px;
  }
.image {
    margin-left: 15px ;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }


Howeveer no joy

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
